# C++ Iterators, what does != really mean?

Tags: c++, stl

I just started looking at this and came across examples like

```
double value1, value2;
std::istream_iterator<double> eos;              // end-of-stream iterator
std::istream_iterator<double> iit (std::cin);   // stdin iterator
if (iit!=eos) value1=*iit;
++iit;
```

So I suppose like anyone with a broad OO background but not recent C I thought WTF!  One would expect to see something like

```
while (iit.next()) ... iit.value()
```

But I can understand that to a C programmer doing pointer arithmetic feels like a natural way to think of an iterator(!!).

So operators like * can be overriden to do quite different things.  But what does the != operator do?  Docs say that this one is not overridden in some weird way.  So how could it possibly work?

I can see from a C point of view this would be like running through string looking for that lovely trailing null.  But here I would not expect there to be some magic double value that is used as a token.  Does it use NaN or something?

Comment: "Docs say that this one is not overridden in some weird way. So how could it possibly work?" What docs say this and where?! The not equals operator is definitely overridden for `std::istream_iterator`.

Comment: `!=` is the DIFFERENT FROM a.k.a. NOT EQUAL operator. When two values compare equal they can be used interchangeably. When two values compare unequal there is some difference so that they can not be used interchangeably.

Comment: `!=` means "not equal". So if a valid iterator is not equal to the end iterator, then it points to an element within the range and can be dereferenced.

Comment: @MrEricSir, it is true that I read tutorial sites rather than the official spec, and they had broken examples.  So overriding != does seem necessary.  But looking at the other replies to this post there are others that are also confused.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf MrEricSir "!=" does not mean anything at all.  If is just a method that can do stuff.  In this case it has nothing to do with the normal meaning of equality.  It says that if the right hand argument is the special token "eos" then return true if the left hand argument is not at the end of the stream.  And that is what is confusing.

Comment: @KerrekSB See above.

Comment: @aberglas: Possibly and probably your misconception is that the word `red` doesn't mean anything, because you can think of contexts  where it means something other than `red`, in particular conversations with folks who haven't grasped what `red` is and use it to refer to oil viscosity. But as I see it it would be just downright dumb to base my explanation of the word on that idea. It has a commonly known accepted meaning, and I simply don't talk with people who insist that `red` means oil viscosity.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In this case itterators seem to be using red to mean viscosity, or worse.  The original API looked so weird to me that I thought I might be misunderstanding something fundamental, hence the post.  But no, it is just a weird API.

Comment: Uhuh. Let's consider the two possible results of `iit != eos`. If it is `true`, as it's likely to be the first few times, then the two values are not interchangeable. You would change things by assigning `eos` to `iit`. But when, finally, it is `false`, then the opposite is true, namely `iit == eos`. In this case the values are interchangeable. You can now assign `eos` to `iit` without changing any observable behavior. This is the fundamental meaning of `!=`. It's irrelevant whether such assignment would change memory bits or not. Just as 1 = 666/666, even though the latter can be offensive.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have:

```
int arr[10];
```

In C, to iterate over the array, the most common used method is:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
   doSomething(arr[i]);
}
```

You can do that in C++ also. However, the C++ programming idiom has evolved where it is more natural to use:

```
int* end = arr + 10;
for ( int* iter = arr; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   doSomething(*iter);
}
```

You can use that idiom to iterate over the containers, such as `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::map`, etc.

```
std::map<int, int> aMap = { ... };

std::map<int, int>::iterator end = aMap.end();
for ( std::map<int, int>::iterator iter = aMap.begin(); iter != end; ++iter )
{
   int key = iter->first;
   int value = iter->second;
   // Use key and value
}
```

Most, if not all, of the functions in the [Standard Algorithms Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) are designed to work with the notion of *iterator*s.

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, by using the new range-`for` loop, the `auto` keyword to deduce variable types, and `std::begin()`, and `std::end()`, the above blocks of code can be further simplified.

For the array:

```
for ( auto val : arr )
{
   doSomething(val);
}
```

or

```
auto end = std::end(arr);
for ( auto iter = std::begin(arr); iter != std::end; ++iter )
{
   doSomething(*iter);
}
```

For the `std::map`:

```
for ( auto& item : aMap )
{
   int key = item.first;
   int value = item.second;
   // Use key and value
}
```

or

```
auto end = std::end(aMap);
for ( auto iter = std::begin(aMap); iter != end; ++iter )
{
   int key = iter->first;
   int value = iter->second;
   // Use key and value
}
```

or

```
auto end = aMap.end();
for ( auto iter = aMap.begin(); iter != end; ++iter )
{
   int key = iter->first;
   int value = iter->second;
   // Use key and value
}
```

Coming to your specific question, [`std::istream_iterator<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is used in a very similar way. It can be used to read data from a `std::istream` and the data can be used in various algorithms. Couple of its important member functions are the [`operator*` and `operator->` overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator*). When those functions are called, the iterator reads one object of type `double` from its associated `std::istream` and returns the data. Hence, you can use it in a `for` loop as:

```
std::istream_iterator<double> iter(std::cin); 
std::istream_iterator<double> end;
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   double val = *iter;
   std::cout << "Got " << val << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, However, you missed the point of my question.  Are you suggesting to itterate through a file, the system first reads the entire file into memory in order to determine what "end" is, and then runs the loop.  I think not.  I think that it must in fact override != to do something quite different to !=.  (Compared to any other language with itterators, the C++ way is very, very strange.  See my original post.)

Comment: @aberglas, the default constructor of `istream_iterator` constructs an object that acts as an *end*. The file is not read into memory to do that. So, you are right about what you are thinking.

Comment: To the original post, no true C programmer would write `doSomething(arr[i]);` due to the perceived inefficiency assuming non-optimizing compilers.  `doSomething(*iter++);` is a C-only idiom, which seems to have then become part of the C++ iterator spec in a very strange way.  There must have been some debate about this at the time, links would be appreciated.

Comment: @aberglas, I don't have any links to published articles on the topic.  I find the following link useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator.

Comment: @r Sahu Thainks for the link, but like all the other links I found it does not talk about the radical redefinition of !=, just * and ++.